# Disable "search on type" completely

Tags: visual-studio-code

Unchecking "search on type" appears to only affect the keyword field, it doesn't disable it for "files to include" and "files to exclude" fields. Any idea how I can disable it completely?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up setting "Search On Type Debounce Period" to a big number, like 30000. Apparently that setting is properly implemented.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I looking for

```
"editor.find.cursorMoveOnType": false
```